# Correct way of modeling my Database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have trouble finding the best solution to create my database. I have 3 entities : Restaurant, Supplier And SubSupplier.
Each restaurant can order to any Supplier. If the Supplier has SubSuppliers, restaurants order directly to one of the SubSupplier but has to know the parent-Supplier for information.

For the moment i have that:

```
Restaurant (idRestaurant,nameRestaurant,otherStuff,...);
Supplier (idSupplier,nameSupplier,address, phone, ...);
SubSupplier (idSubSupplier, #idSupplier, nameSubSupplier, address, phone,...) ;
```

But Suppliers and SubSuppliers have exactly the same attributes (like 20) except that the SubSupplier is linked to a parent-Supplier.

I don't really know how to do that correctly because Suppliers and SubSupliers have almost everything in common and i find it repetitive to create 2 distincts table.

Is this a good solution ? What's best ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have one table for the suppliers, and sub suppliers; with a nullable part "bunny ear" relation. It's then just a left join to find the parent, if there is one, when ordering.

Answer (score 1):

A sub-supplier is still a supplier so you shouldn't create a new table for it. What you need is a third table to establish the parent/child relationship between two suppliers. A "sub-supplier" is the child of a supplier. For instance:

```
Restaurant (idRestaurant,nameRestaurant,otherStuff,...);
Supplier (idSupplier,nameSupplier,address, phone, ...);
SupplierChild (idParentSupplier, idChildSupplier)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add a column (superSupplier) to the table Supplier with an ID referenced (foreign key) to a Supplier, so it would be like if you are telling to a Supplier who is its superSupplier and if the value is null, then it's a normal Supplier.